# Pine Script Alerts issue or question? To me a Odd one

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am working on alerting via webhooks, and I have it working in an oddball type. However, I need it to work without having to do the workaround.

```
smaLong = ta.crossover(fastMa, slowMa)
smaShort = ta.crossunder(fastMa, slowMa)

//if smaLong
SL = '{"content": "@everyone" ,"embeds": [{"title": "{{ticker}} 3M :chart_with_upwards_trend:","description": "SMA LONG\n Might want to look at CALLS here!\n Price ${{close}}", "color": "2092045","author": {"name":null},"timestamp": "{{timenow}}"}],"username": "Alertbot"}'
SS = '{"content": "@everyone","embeds": [{"title": "{{ticker}} 3M :chart_with_downwards_trend:","description": "SMA SHORT\n Might want look at PUTS here!\nPrice ${{close}}", "color": "14681898","author": {"name":null},"timestamp": "{{timenow}}"}],"username": "Alertbot"}'

alertcondition(condition=smaLong,title="Webhook SMA Long", message= SL)
alertcondition(condition=smaShort,title="Webhook SMA Short", message= SS)
```

Here is where it gets odd, if I create an alert and point it to the above, it doesn't work or pushes it out to the webhook. However, The alert log shows it was sent, but nothing in the discord, but if I copy and paste one of the SL or SS above without the ' ' in the message body of the alert settings, it works.

[image]

I have attached a screenshot that shows the SSL is the one that is set up via the script, but the other one without a label is just a copy and paste of the JSON code.

Comment: Post a screenshot hovering your mouse over one of the triggered log events. It will show the entire alert message, with variables substituted.

Comment: Done that, and it looks just like the JSON information in the message.  What is odd is that in the script, there are "\n" in there, but that "\n" isn't being passed into the message box when setting up the alert.

Comment: That could be the shortcoming of the tooltip as it is not able to show newlines (but consumes the newline character).

Comment: Reduce the payload to a single character to check if the error is in the message body itself. But I'm interested how do you call the Discord API as I can call it via `curl` but that uses HTTP POST and passes the payload to a `content` variable which I'm not aware how you can do with Tradingview custom HTTP signal.

Comment: What is odd .. if the new lines are there ... If I copy and past that part of the script into the message area, the alter goes works perfectly.  Just not the way it "should," lol.  So at this point, until I can figure it out, I just remove the \n at this time.

Comment: Not getting or seeing any errors.  Just using the Discord webhook API. Build out the code based on the discohook output and then from there to the SS or SL variable.